# jquery validation on multiple object with same class

Tags: jquery, validation

I have a scenario where i am clonning textboxes. then for each box input i validate it against db ( via ajax call) whether the input is correct or wrong. if it input is invalid i show an error box and at the end i have a jquery validator method which checks if any box has error msg then it raise error and form do not post. but the problem is validtor show error msg for all textbox whether value is right or wrong.

```
         <table id="next_module" class="table">
                <thead>
                        <th>Message Id</th>

                </thead>
                <tbody>


        <tr id="row_0">
                    <td>
                        <input id="messge-id_0" class="valid_next_messge_module numeric messgeing_id required" name="messge-id_0" type="text" onblur="get_messge_detail($(this));" value="">
                        <label id="txterr_0" class="next_messge_error" style="display: none;color:red;width:0px">*</label></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>


            <script>
            var $underscore = $("#next_module tbody tr:first");
            var $clone = $underscore.clone();
            $clone.attr('id', $clone.attr("id") + i );
            $clone
            .find("input,label")
            .each(function() {
                $(this).attr({
                    id: this.id + i,
                    name: this.name + i,
                    value:'',
                    src:''
                });
            });
            $clone
            .appendTo("#next_module")
            .show();
            i++;
            </script>



            <script>
            function get_messge_detail(obj)
            {
                var messge_id = $.trim(obj.val());
                var id_num = (obj.attr('id')).split('_')[1];
                if(messge_id)
                {
                var url = "/server/messge/ajax_get_messge_detail/";
                var data = {'messge_id':messge_id};

                $.ajaxSetup({async:false});

                $.post(url, data, function (response) {


                    if (response["msg"])
                    {
                        no error found 
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $("#"+(obj.attr('id'))).focus();
                        $("#txterr_"+ id_num).show();
                    }
                });
            }

            jQuery.validator.addMethod("valid_next_messge_module", function() {
                var status  =  false;
                if (parseInt( $('.next_messge_error:visible').length) > 0)
                    return false;
                else
                    return true;
            }, "Please enter valid next messgeing module id.");

            </script>
```

Comment: is this approach correct and second if there are 3 boxes and one has invalid value even then validator adds error msgs for all boxes.